# To Find value of this infinite product $P=\frac{7}{9} \frac{26}{28} \frac{63}{65}...\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}...$

Tags: calculus

Given

$$P=\frac{7}{9} \frac{26}{28} \frac{63}{65}...\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}...$$

I have no idea how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the factorizations
$$
n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1),\qquad n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1).
$$
Moreover, $n^2+n+1$ evaluated at $n-1$ gives $n^2-n+1$. Therefore
$$
P=\frac{1\cdot 7}{3\cdot 3}\frac{2\cdot 13}{4\cdot 7}\frac{3\cdot 21}{5\cdot 13}\cdots = \frac{1\cdot 2}{3}.
$$

Comment: why are you evaluating $n^2+n+1$ at $n-1$

Comment: The series telescopes because the top terms of the fractions are shifted versions of the bottom. So the point is that shifting the index of the $n^2+n+1$ up top gives the $n^2-n+1$ on the bottom.

Comment: I did not understand. Can you explain it in detail

Comment: The 7 in the n=1 numerator cancels the 7 in the n=2 term. The 13 in the n=2 term cancels the 13 in the n=3 term, and so on. The 3 in the n=1 denominator cancels the 3 in the n=3 numerator and so on. All that remains uncanceled is the 1 from the n=1 numerator, the 2 from the n=2 numerator, and the other 3 from the n=1 denominator.

Comment: The product starts from n=2. At n=1 it get to 0

Comment: Right, there was an off-by-one error in that last comment, but the idea is clear from the product written in my answer.

Comment: Yeah i got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did it by trying to guess a partial product formula, then proving by induction.

Assume that
$$P(n)=\prod_{n=2}^{n}\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\frac{n^2+n+1}{n(n+1)}$$
Note that
$$P(n+1)=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\frac{n^2+3n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)}=P(n)\frac{(n+1)^3-1}{(n+1)^3+1}$$
and confirm $P(2)=\frac{7}{9}$.

Now conclude by calculating
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(n)=\frac{2}{3}$$